# Gradle custom configuration copy always up todate

Tags: gradle

I have some wierd issues in my Gradle script.Basically I am trying to copy all the files from a particular configuration into a folder and the copy task is always up to-date.

I have multilevel projects and in the subprojects section I apply java plugin and then creating configuration just to download files from Nexus into a folder which we will be using it for different purpose.However if I am using custom configuration in the copy task it says always up todate but if I mention those files in compile configuration then it copies fine.

Below code is not working

```
subprojects{
    apply plugin : 'java'
    //version is set from Jenkins job
    version=System.env['version']
    configurations{
         downloadProjectAFiles
         downloadProjectBFiles
    }
    dependencies{   
        downloadProjectAFiles 'com.project.test:ProjectA:version'
        downloadProjectAFiles 'com.project.test:ProjectA:version'
    }
}

task copyProjectA(type : Copy){
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false } 
    from project(':ProjectA').configurations.downloadProjectAFiles
    into someFolder
}

task copyProjectB(type : Copy){
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false } 
    from project(':ProjectB').configurations.downloadProjectBFiles
    into someFolder
}

copyProjectB.dependsOn('copyProjectA')
```

below code is working

```
subprojects{
    apply plugin : 'java'
    //version is set from Jenkins job
    version=System.env['version']
    configurations{
         downloadProjectAFiles
         downloadProjectBFiles
    }
    dependencies{   
        compile 'com.project.test:ProjectA:version'
        compile 'com.project.test:ProjectA:version'
    }
}

task copyProjectA(type : Copy){
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false } 
    from project(':ProjectA').configurations.compile
    into someFolder
}

task copyProjectB(type : Copy){
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false } 
    from project(':ProjectB').configurations.compile
    into someFolder
}

copyProjectB.dependsOn('copyProjectA')
```

Comment: What exactly You want to download? When `compile` is used You'll get project's dependencies, and that's ok. With `downloadProjectAFiles` there are no files defined.

Comment: OK. I should have been more specific.Project A and Project B basically generates Jar files and upload them into Nexus repository whenever you run a build and sometimes we would like to download a specific version of these jar files and move them to a folder where it is being used by other processes.So we are passing the version we are intended to download.

I do not understand your explanation as you can see I defined a dependencies for the configurations downloadProjectAFiles and downloadProjectBFiles .is that not enough to download them from Nexus?